# Duplicate spreadsheet file and change its name to the date when it was duplicated

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

```
function saveAsSpreadsheet(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"); 
  DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy("desired file name", destFolder);
}
```

How to make a the "desired file name" to be the date which the script is run (weekly basis)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script names the file as 2016-05-19, using `Utilities.formatDate`:

```
var fileName = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy(fileName, destFolder);
```

Refer to  [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) documentation for other format options.

Comment: Thank you very much for editing and answering my 1st question on stackoverflow. It works perfectly.

Comment: Glad it works. On Stack Overflow, one usually marks one of the answers as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark next to it, after the problem is solved.